# How to persist multiple entities as fast as i can Symfony 5

Tags: database, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i'm trying to add xlsx data to my data base as entities i wrote this script

```
$batchCount = 10000;
$i = 0;
foreach($rows as $row) {
                if (is_numeric($row[0])){
                    $i++;
                    $cart = new Carte();
                    //doing something
                    $this->em->persist($cart);
                    if (($i % $batchCount) == 0) {
                        $this->em->flush();
                        $this->em->clear();
                   }
                }
            }
```

But for a adding 50,000 line in database its taking to long
I'd love if some one have fast method to add large data to database using Symfony

Comment: While Doctrine is easy to use with Symfony it is not actually part of Symfony.  So if Symfony is your only requirement then drop down to using SQL via either the Doctrine DBAL connection or even PDO itself.  It will be much faster though frankly trying to do 50K of anything in PHP is not going to be very fast.